# HTML Local File area

Tags: html

I'm creating a series of web pages and I want them all to be linked together from a navigation bar, I currently have:

```
 <li><a href="file:///C:\Users\Corey\Documents\Web Project\Creation.html#CreationXHTML">XHTML & HTML</a></li>
```

However, if I need to export these files to another computer wouldn't the link be wrong and then not work? 
How would I change these links so the file containing the HTML, CSS can be zipped up emailed to someone and it still work for them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use relative links - no need to include the `file:///.....`. This will also mean if you upload it to the web or zip all the files together and send to someone else, it will still work - assuming of course you maintain the same folder structure and relative file locations.

For example I have a root folder with my index.html file which has the navigation links and a folder structure as below with `firstpost.html` and `secondpost.html` in the blog folder.

***Web Project* folder structure**

```
index.html
Creation.html
blog/ (folder)
  firstpost.html
  secondpost.html
```

**example links in `index.html`**

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="Creation.html#CreationXHTML">XHTML & HTML</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="blog/firstpost.html">First Post</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="blog/secondpost.html">Second Post</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

check out [this post](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa040502a.htm) that will give you a basic overview of the idea of absolute vs relative paths.

Comment: You can choose one of our answers as correct, and upvote as you think appropriate if you've figured it out

Answer (score 1):

Use relative URLs.

```
<li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="folder/page.html">Something</a></li>
```

The path is relative to the current file, `home.html`, `about.html`, and `contact.html` are all in the same folder, while `page.html` is in a subfolder named 'folder'.